# Change Flutter String Color

Tags: string, flutter, colors

I am defining Strings in a class TextFile as

```dart
class TextFile {

..

..

**static const String TIMER = "Timer";**

}
```

And I am using this in another file as
**TextFile.TIMER**

There is no Text Widget Used

I am using it in a model defined as,

```
    class SideMenuModel { 
    String name; 
    dynamic icon; 
    bool selected; 
    String imgpath; 
    String whiteimgpath;

    SideMenuModel(this.name, 
    this.icon, 
    this.selected,
    {this.imgpath,this.whiteimgpath}); 
    }
```

and then appending that to a list. Like,

```
    _navigationList.add(SideMenuModel(TextFile.TIMER, Icons.timer,
    false,imgpath:"image/Timer.png",whiteimgpath:"image/newTimer.png"));
```

> *Now, how do I change the color of this String?*

Please Respond. I am Stuck.

Comment: Can you post the other code snippet as well where you have used this string ?

Comment: Do you mean you like change the String value ? And where are you applying this variable and where you like to change it.  btw it is const .

Comment: I just have used it once. 
I need to change the color of the String. 
Black to Blue

Comment: You need to change the color of string at place you are using it, for example your Text widget or something like that.

Comment: I am not using a Text Widget. @BorisGrigorov